# matplotlibのplt.imshow で表示したwindowの描画がされないが、再描画させると表示する

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

下のようなプログラムをpycharmで動かした際のトラブルです。

matplotlibで画像を表示するウィンドウが、空白で表示されます。
matplotlibのウィンドウに付属する拡大ボタンを押して、ドラッグで拡大をさせると、拡大した画像が表示されます。
プログラム自体は「プロセスは終了コード 0 で終了しました」とエラーはありません。

同じプログラムをターミナルから走らせた場合や、Intel CPUのMac、Windowsで走らせた場合は、問題なく表示されますし、

数日前は問題なかったので、M2 Mac固有あるいは何かのアップデートが原因と思いますが、
問題の切り分けや対応方法がわかりません。

対処方法を教えていただければ幸いです。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.linspace(0,1,25).reshape(5,5)
im = plt.imshow(data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `print(matplotlib.get_backend())` で何が出ますか？
import 辺りに `%matplotlib inline` の行を入れると変化有りますか？
他に `matplotlib.use('module://backend_interagg')` などの指定もあるので inlineの行の代わりに試してみるとなにか変化あるかも

Comment: print(matplotlib.get_backend())の出力:MacOSXでした。%matplotlib inlineをいくつかの場所に入れてみたところ、syntax errorが出てきました。matplotlib.use('module://backend_interagg')をいくつかの場所に変えて動作させみると、ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend_interagg'と出てきました。